# Load data.csv when installing plugin

Tags: php, mysql, csv, wordpress

I am new to wordpress plugin development. I want to create a new table when someone installs the plugin and populate the daata from csv file into the table.

Here is my code to create table:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `location` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `slug` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `population` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id) 
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

After running this table is created.

Issue is that I am finding it difficult to populate data.csv into the table.

In windows xampp it is working

```
$current_plugin_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$current_plugin_dir = str_replace("\\","\\\\",$current_plugin_dir);
$current_plugin_dir = $current_plugin_dir . '\\\\data.csv';
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$current_plugin_dir' INTO TABLE $table_name";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

While live server it is not working... But following code works...

```
$current_plugin_dir = $current_plugin_dir.'/data.csv';
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$current_plugin_dir' INTO TABLE $table_name";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

But in my ubuntu operating system no one seems to work.. I debugged and it seems following query ran on ubuntu lamp environment

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/testwp/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/data.csv' INTO TABLE test_population
```

and it triggered following error

> ## 1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Is there any single way of loading csv on all platforms? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it as an additional option when setting up your connection:

```
mysql -u myuser -p --local-infile yourdatabase
```

or put it in your my.cnf file:

```
[client]
loose-local-infile=1
```

This is because that feature opens a security hole and is disabled by default. So you have to enable it manually in case you want to use it.

An other option is to read file by using fopen() and usual sql inserts.

Comment: Where should i put **mysql -u myuser -p --local-infile yourdatabase** in wordpress?

Comment: Nowhere, this must be done on server level, but in order your plugin to be useful everywhere you should consider not to use LOAD DATA INFILE.